# Cannot Call 'Helpers' Class at app.components from my modules model

Tags: php, class, yii, components

I have a problem that I cannot call 'Helpers' class which placed at `application.components`

I already set import component on my main.php as `'application.components.*'`

but still getting error when call `Helpers::someMethod('some-data')`, the error is `Fatal error: Class 'Helpers' not found in /path/ lines`

Comment: Is it maybe a problem of naming?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by import the class where I need to access the method by add `Yii::import('application.components.Helpers');` on the early line of the page.